# How To Include JavaScript Files Only In Single Posts?

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I know that `wp_enqueue_script()` inserts Javascript files into the WordPress header in the appropriate place.

However, I want to include my Javascript in all single posts, ignoring the WordPress home or blog page.
Is that possible at all?

I tried this:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

if you want it on all single posts as well as pages & custom post types, use `is_singular()` instead of `is_single()`

& just in case you're using it on the template, this code goes in functions.php

UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO THE COMMENTS

write this code just above your `wp_head()` function in header.php

```
global $wp_scripts;
var_dump($wp_scripts);
```

This will display on the site all the info related to scripts registered in wordpress to be displayed. Read it & then see what scripts you want to display & what scripts are to be removed with [wp_dequeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

To determine which page you are removing scripts from, you may look for various [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: My Wordpress Home Page is too heavy with jquery, javascript bla bla. i'm trying to remove javascript who not necessary on home page. so i want to implement on my wordpress template. Please let me know, some trick to filter javasript on wordpress home page.

Comment: All these javascript come form wordpress plugins

Comment: This would have to be done on a plugin-by-plugin basis then as they most likely would all have unique script enqueue names.  Also, you may risk having JavaScript errors popup on your home page if you just disable the scripts without disabling the plugins.

Comment: so how i implement on plugin? i tested is_single() its not working

Comment: Updated the answer above

Comment: You cannot just magically alter how a plugin is adding scripts, you will have to look at each plugin to see how they are doing it.

Comment: Why not? They are all added via some handle, you can dequeue them easily. Though you should see what each script is doing so as to not remove a script you require

Comment: Unfortunately not all plugins follow the rules when it comes to enqueueing scripts.  There's a very good chance that between plugins and themes you'll have at least one instance where something is directly echoing a call for script inclusion.

Comment: i edit one plugin and used check if ( is_singular() ) and if ( !is_home() ) both not properly working. is_singular() neglect javascript from both home and post and 2ad not neglect from both sides.